# Share via Facebook in iOS6 - Settings button not working

Tags: iphone, facebook, ios6, settings, social-framework

I wish to share my app via Facebook.

When I have not configured my Facebook account, I get the below error.
**When I tap on "Settings", it doesn't work. 'Settings' and 'cancel' gives the same result.**

[image: Error image attached]

Hence, I imported Social.framework.

```
#import <Social/Social.h>
```

Below is the method used.

```
-(IBAction) facebookBtnCall{

NSString *facebookTxt = @"Facebook Text";
NSString *AppUrl = @"http://www.google.co.in/";
NSString *ImageUrl = @"http://www.phoolwala.com/adminpanel/uploads/small/1303380733-PHW-B-18-RP-R.jpg";

float version = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];

if (version >= 6.0) {

    if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) {
        SLComposeViewController *fbComposer = [SLComposeViewController
                                               composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
        //set the initial text message
        [fbComposer setInitialText:facebookTxt];
        //add url
        if ([fbComposer addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:AppUrl]]) {
            NSLog(@"Blog url added");
        }

        // you can remove all added URLs as follows
        //[fbComposer removeAllURLs];

        //add image to post
        if ([fbComposer addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:ImageUrl]]) {
            NSLog(@"strong binary added to the post");
        }
        if ([fbComposer addImage:[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:ImageUrl]]]]) {
            NSLog(@"scan is added to the post");
        }

        //remove all added images
        //[fbComposer removeAllImages];

        //present the composer to the user
        [self presentViewController:fbComposer animated:YES completion:nil];

    }
}
else {
    NSLog(@"Load facebook on webview");
}
}
```

Comment: `Ambili B Menon` Check your condition code properly

Comment: What happens when you go into the Facebook section of the Settings app directly?

Also, you should consider using the Facebook SDK for iOS (https://developers.facebook.com/ios/) since it will handle support for different iOS versions for you.

Comment: 'Settings' and 'cancel' gives the same result.

Comment: I'm having the same exact issue as you. Did you ever get it resolved?

Comment: Did you put your facebook app id in the Info.plist?

Comment: Yea. appId is already added to the Info.plist.

Comment: is there a fix for this? I facing the same issue

Comment: Am getting same issue in IOS 7 .how can i solve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried doing something like this:

```
    SLComposeViewController *fbController = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];

if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) {
    SLComposeViewControllerCompletionHandler __block completionHandler=^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result){

        [fbController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

        switch(result){
            case SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled:
            default:
            {
                NSLog(@"Cancelled.....");

            }
                break;
            case SLComposeViewControllerResultDone:
            {
                NSLog(@"Posted....");
            }
                break;
        }};

    //[fbController addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.jpg"]];
    [fbController setInitialText:@"Test message"];
    [fbController addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.asset.url]];
    [fbController setCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
    [self presentViewController:fbController animated:YES completion:nil];
} else {
    NSLog(@"no facebook setup");
}
```

Comment: Hi Ambili B Menon, Have you got any solution. I am also getting this issue. If you any solution please update it.

Comment: @user1120998 Not yet :(